# libgdx distorted texture when using camera.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

Tags: java, android, textures

I'am trying to make libgdx game, adn i've got 2 problems now:
1. When im using camera.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);  my textrure of player is distored, one eye is bigger than another.
2. Im using this camera and viweport:

```
camera= new OrthographicCamera(GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT);
camera.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
viewport = new StretchViewport(GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT,camera);
```

and when i do  :

```
touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(1),Gdx.input.getY(1),0);
 game.camera.unproject(touchPos);
System.out.println(touchPos.x+" "+ touchPos.y);
```

I get 0 0 in right top corner but my character witch cords 0 0 is drawing in left bottom corner.

When i use:

```
 game.camera = new OrthographicCamera(820,480);
game.viewport = new FillViewport(820,480,game.camera);
```

i must use  game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(game.camera.combined);

when i use this code i've got corectly working unproject method and coordinate system but i've got distored texture.

When i use:

```
camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
viewport = new StretchViewport(900, 470, camera);
```

i've got distored texture and bad coords system. and i can 't use :game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(game.camera.combined);

Comment: For the second issue check the accepted answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104364/apply-pixel-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates

Comment: thx unproject started to work.

Comment: Does everything work now? Then I will create the comment as the answer so people later clearly see the solution.

Comment: nope, still got problem with distored pixel

Comment: Do you include your texture properly? Does it also occur with another camera/ viewport?

Comment: I include texture like this hoodieTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("hoodieTexture.png"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is distorted because you are using a fixed width and height for the camera, so it simply stretches to fit whatever size window/screen you're putting it on.

Incidentally, StretchViewport does the same thing (distorts the scene to fit the dimensions you gave it to the window). But you just created a viewport without actually calling `update()` on it, so it's not doing anything.

You most likely want to use ExtendViewport or FillViewport to avoid stretching, but other options are available. Read about them [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

Your viewport won't properly respond to screen rotations (or desktop window resize) unless you put `viewport.update(width,height)` into the resize method. And you have to call `update` on it at least once regardless, using the actual screen dimensions. This is most convenient by simply putting `viewport.update(width,height)` into the resize method.

Comment: Which one of these viewports do you recomend to use in pixel art game which use entire screen as a game area ?

Comment: Is there anyway  to have no black bars an no distored texture ? How professionals do this ?

Comment: See my answer on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909056/java-libgdx-1-20-version-texture-bug